# Pass a Variable Up the Navigation Stack? - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, variables

I am able to pass a variable forward from view controller to view controller by pushing its view controller onto the navigation stack. An example of how I do it would be this:

```
MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.myString = stringToPass;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

However, what do I do if I want to pass a variable BACK UP the navigation stack? Using popViewControllerAnimated rather than pushViewController does not pass the variable up like I thought it would.

I need to be able to access the variable several pops up from the view controller it is defined in.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing values, not variables.

A view controller should not be responsible for popping itself. With Apple's view controllers (e.g. UIImagePicker), it is the parent view controller's responsibility to do the popping; the parent VC can also obtain the current value. (Not entirely correct; it might access the value before a keyboard autocompletion is applied)

Alternatively, if it's a value that can be shared globally, you can store it in your application delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a hold of the navigation controller in the VC stack using self.navigationController. You can just call some method like

```
[self.navigationController setMyString:stringToPassUp];
```

There are several more ways, e.g. self.tabBarController for the tabbarcontroller up in the stack, or most simply

```
[self.parentViewController setMyString:stringToPassUp];
```

**edit** given the downvotes on the examples above, and nobody giving a better explanation, let's discuss the *proper* way to do this.

If you have some object (like your `MyViewController *controller`) and that object has something to tell you, the usual approach is this:

- MyViewController gets a `delegate` property, of type `(id)`
- the view controller instantiating the MyViewController, sets this delegate property, like so:
  `controller.delegate = self;`
- MyViewController will, when it has something to say, do something like:
  `[self.delegate delegateMessage:arg1];` to "pass the message up" as you put it.

To do it perfectly, you may want to create your own `@protocol MyViewControllerDelegate`, and declare the class which would be setting `controller.delegate = self;` to adopt this protocol, by putting `<MyViewControllerDelegate>` on the @interface line. The `delegate` property of MyViewController should then be declared `id<MyViewControllerDelegate> delegate;`, so that the `[self.delegate ...]` messages can be matched to the protocol specification.

Basically the whole Cocoa Touch API works like this. Just have a look around for ideas how to implement your interaction.

Comment: They're not mine, but I presume they're because you're promoting some wonky flow-control ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In the end I decided to use my app delegate as that seemed the simplest (and most common) solution.

Comment: one day, you will regret that ;-)