# IPHONE How to access variables from other classes/viewcontrollers

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a app that uses several view controllers. In one instance I need to uses an int (int lives) in a seperate view controller from where it is created. I have tried using it and it throws and error at build claiming "lives" undeclared. I am already importing the view controller where the int was declared. I am stuck on this one.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use properties, or custom setter and getter for instanse variables.

Comment: Thanks for the instant replies! Could you give me a quick example of how I might do this using an int?

Comment: - (int)getMyIntVariable { return myIntVariable; }

Answer (score 0):

You could use the application delegate to store information you need in different places in you app.

The proper way would be to implement your own delegate protocol. For a recent discussion on this topic, see [pass a variable up the navigation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398339/pass-a-variable-up-the-navigation-stack-iphone/3398392#3398392)

Comment: After looking around the app delegate looks like the place to do it. Do I just store variables in appdelegate.h and then does that make it global??

Comment: almost, you need to declare them, add a @property line, and add a @synthesize line in the `.m` file. Then you can access them using getters/setters, like `[appDelegate setMyValue:5];` where `addDelegate` should point to your app delegate.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I still get a couple of build warnings and runs fine until I call the get method. 
//  ViewControllerDemoAppDelegate.h
NSInteger *MyInt;

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger *MyInt;

//  ViewControllerDemoAppDelegate.m
@synthesize MyInt;

MyInt = 5;

[release MyInt];

//levelpassed.m
#import "ViewControllerDemoAppDelegate.h"

fish = [ViewControllerDemoAppDelegate getMyInt];

BW- 1) ViewControllerDemoAppDelegate may not respond to "+getMyInt"

2) Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Should I be using NSInteger? Am I using the properties correctly?

Comment: Not entirely correct: 1) declare it `NSInteger myInt` without `*`, 2) you should not call `getMyInt` but just `myInt`, and 3) you need to call it on the app delegate instance object, not the class. Easiest way for that is `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] myInt]`